# How to adjust the spaces between elements in inline-block layout?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout without using grid or flexbox, I am using `display: inline-block` to achieve that but i have a problem with adjusting spaces.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align : justify;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.header {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background: #eee;
}

.main > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">
       <div class="item">item1</div>
       <div class="item">item2</div>
       <div class="item">item3</div>
       <div class="item">item4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
 </div>
```

[image]

I am trying to achieve the same effect as `justify-content: space-between` in flexbox
but i got elements that are not aligned well in the layout.

I can fix the spaces around item4 but using `margin-left` but i don't like this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden element to trigger the `justify` alignment for the last line but you will need to use a negative `margin-bottom` to remove the extra line added.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align : justify;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.header {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background: #eee;
}

.main > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: #eee;
}
.main:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:5%;
  height:50px; /* we consider a bigger value than the line-height*/
}
.main {
  margin-bottom:-50px; /*the same value defined in the pseuo element*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">
       <div class="item">item1</div>
       <div class="item">item2</div>
       <div class="item">item3</div>
       <div class="item">item4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
 </div>
```

Or use `font-size:0` trick to avoid that extra line:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align : justify;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.header {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background: #eee;
}

.main > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: #eee;
  font-size:initial;
}
.main:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:5%;
}
.main {
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="main">
       <div class="item">item1</div>
       <div class="item">item2</div>
       <div class="item">item3</div>
       <div class="item">item4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this without setting the spacing. As you probably know, you can get better control of inline-block layouts setting negative letter-spacing on the container and resetting on the item: `.main {letter-spacing: -4px} .item {letter-spacing: 0}` (You need to test if 4px works).

Or (since we're not using flex :), you could float odd and even divs left and right: `.item:nth-child(odd) {clear: left; float: left} .item:nth-child(even) {float: right}`